# Catch express bodyParser error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to catch the error from the bodyParser() middleware when I send a json object and it is invalid because I want to send a custom response instead of a generic 400 error.

This is what I have and it works:

```
app.use (express.bodyParser ());
app.use (function (error, req, res, next){
    //Catch bodyParser error
    if (error.message === "invalid json"){
        sendError (res, myCustomErrorMessage);
    }else{
        next ();
    }
});
```

But this seems to me a very ugly approach because I'm comparing the error message which could change in future express versions. There's any other way to catch bodyParser() errors?

EDIT:

This is the error when the request body has an invalid json:

```
{
  stack: 'Error: invalid json\n    at Object.exports.error (<path>/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:55:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (<path>/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:74:71)\n    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)\n    at _stream_readable.js:872:14\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)',
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'invalid json',
  status: 400
}
```

Pretty printed stack:

```
Error: invalid json
    at Object.exports.error (<path>/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:55:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (<path>/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:74:71)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:872:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found it:

bodyParser() is a convenience function for json(), urlencoded() and multipart(). I just need to call to json(), catch the error and call to urlencoded() and multipart().

[bodyParser source](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html)

```
app.use (express.json ());
app.use (function (error, req, res, next){
    //Catch json error
    sendError (res, myCustomErrorMessage);
});

app.use (express.urlencoded ());
app.use (express.multipart ());
```

Comment: That is not a solution. You don't take into consideration that before this code could be another middleware. If you catch in such way some exception it could lead to unpredictable state. At least it's better to write: `app.use(function (error, req, res, next) { /* Shutdown node */ }; app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(function(error, req, res, next) { /* if err.status == 4** then handle json error => res.status(400).send(), else shutdown node */ });`

Comment: DANGER DANGER, this catches any error in above middleware, as @Dao said.  Unsafe

Answer (score 30):

I think your best bet is to check for `SyntaxError`:

```
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    sendError(res, myCustomErrorMessage);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it's not a SyntaxError. See question update.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas With the newest version of Express (4.6.1) the `bodyParser` module is no longer built-in, it has been moved into it's own [module](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and that does indeed throw a `SyntaxError` for malformed JSON.

Comment: If the request body is too large, however, you'll get an Error instead of a SyntaxError.  For example: `{ [Error: request entity too large]
  type: 'entity.too.large',
  message: 'request entity too large',
  statusCode: 413,
  status: 413,
  expected: 322350,
  length: 322350,
  limit: 102400 }`

Comment: Just check for `instanceof SyntaxError` and then `instanceof Error`, or treat them the same. 

Question: if any error occurs when parsing JSON, `error` will be truthy, and otherwise will be false-y, right?

Comment: @WillBrickner `error` will always be truthy there, the handler is _only_ called when an error has happened. But the error can be anything, it's a generic Express error handler.

Answer (score 26):

From the answer of @alexander but with an example of usage

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    bodyParser.json({
        verify: addRawBody,
    })(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(400);
            return;
        }
        next();
    });
});

function addRawBody(req, res, buf, encoding) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, very clear but is there a way to make it shorter ? Do the verify param is needed ?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe i'll take another look at the docs to see if there is a shorter way

Answer (score 10):

what I did was just:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }))
// body parser error catcher
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(400).send('error parsing data')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Comment: As I was using bodyParser.json() as well (which is now deprecated), this was perfect for me.

Answer (score 4):

All errors include a type property from 1.18.0 release onwards. For parse failure, err.type === 'entity.parse.failed'.

```
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
if (error.type === 'entity.parse.failed') {
 sendError(res, myCustomErrorMessage);
} else {
 next();
}
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. But where sendError func comes from?

Answer (score 1):

I found checking for `SyntaxError` to be not enough, therefore I do:

```
if (err instanceof SyntaxError &&
  err.status >= 400 && err.status < 500 &&
  err.message.indexOf('JSON') !== -1) {
    // process filtered exception here
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` use is wrong. It will return `-1` if it isn't found which is truthy in javascript. The only way that won't work is if `JSON` is first in the string. It should be `err.message.indexOf('JSON') !== -1`

Answer (score 1):

create new module "hook-body-parser.js"
hook everything with body parser over here

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

module.exports = () => {
  return [
    (req, res, next) => {
      bodyParser.json()(req, res, (error) => {
        if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
          res.sendStatus(400);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    },
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
  ];
};
```

and use over express like this

...
app.use(hookBodyParser())
...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to catch all errors thrown by body-parsr for example
**entity.too.large** or **encoding.unsupported**

just place this middleware right after your body-parser initialization

```
$ npm i express-body-parser-error-handler
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-body-parser-error-handler

for example:

```
const bodyParserErrorHandler = require('express-body-parser-error-handler')
const { urlencoded, json } = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    return res.json({message:""});
});

// body parser initilization
app.use('/', json({limit: '250'}));

// body parser error handler
app.use(bodyParserErrorHandler());
app.use(router);
...
```

Answer (score -4):

```
(bodyParser, req, res) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        bodyParser(req, res, err => {
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
})
```

Bullet-proof. Future-aware. WTFPL-Licensed. And also useful w/ async/await.

Comment: How would I plug this function into my app as middleware thereafter? Where do I put the code which actually responds to the error? What is this doing?

Comment: Please explain how to integrate it to an express application and how does it work.