# Many-to-Many Reference Set Up In Mongo/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, curl, mongoose

I'm having trouble writing a curl script for my Carts table. The Carts tables has a reference to the User and Product table. Here is the model:

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
      const userId = (options.user && options.user._id) || false
      ret.editable = userId && userId.equals(doc._owner)
      return ret
    }
  }
})

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema)

module.exports = Cart
```

So I can create a document in the Carts table in the mongo shell with the insert command:

```
db.cart.insert({"owner" : ObjectId("595153ad6f18427ef38c416b"), "product" : ObjectId("5951976290fe850d650ae4c1")})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

But when I write a curl script like so:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:4741/carts \
  -H 'authorization: Token token=B3vDp2Ay310wxNjPx5EMecMSFmqnUnmnD98yeaLnsjs=--FXJqlTfi/3Xoj15rjF8wZhbMTHN2tkNZaN5ej+WAG4U=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
        "cart": {
             "owner" : ObjectId("595153ad6f18427ef38c416b"),
              "product" : ObjectId("5951976290fe850d650ae4c1")
          }
      }'
```

I get this 500 Internal Server error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
        "error": {}
    }
}
```

I don't think its a problem with the backend because when I got to the localhost:4741/carts url I can see the document that I created. If I could get a pair of second eyes on this issue I would really appreciate it.

--UPDATE--

Follow up, so I looked in my controller to see what I was sending as a request and here's what I found. Here's what I have for my create request:

```
const create = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const cart = Object.assign(req.body.cart, {
    owner: req.user._id,
    product: req.product._id

  })
  Cart.create(cart)
    .then(cart =>
      res.status(201)
        .json({
          cart: cart.toJSON({ virtuals: true, user: req.user })
        }))
    .catch(next)
```

When I log the 'req.body' i get:

```
{ '{"cart": {"owner" : ObjectId("595153ad6f18427ef38c416b"), "product" : ObjectId("5951976290fe850d650ae4c1")}}': '' }
POST /carts 500 16.577 ms - 74
```

but when I log 'req.body.cart' i get:

```
undefined
POST /carts 500 68.882 ms - 74
```

Do I use the node body-parser to transmit the data that isn't being read? I'm at a loss for what to do next.

Comment: You have `ObjectId` within a "string". Just use the values instead. i.e `"owner" : "595153ad6f18427ef38c416b"`. Otherwise it's not valid JSON and being discarded by the body parser. Don't worry about the "type" since Mongoose will sort that out and "cast" for you.

Comment: Honestly, that "should" be logging an error. If not then you should also look here [Catch express bodyParser error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819337/catch-express-bodyparser-error) and have something like that implemented during your development cycle at least. Since logging the error on parsing would have made this problem quite clear.

Comment: Because you are also missing the `"application/json"` Content-Type. Add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to your curl command. I can see in the `console.log(req.body)` that the content is "still" being considered a "string". Hence why there was no error logged on parsing. See the quotes `''` around the ouput.

Comment: Neil you got it! You're life saver, thank you so much!!