# How to fetch server node js errors?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I built auth application in Node.js and Express. Now I'm writing the backend.
I use MongoDB database.

I use post query to login page with next JSON data.

THERE ERROR - EMAIL FIELD MUST BE IN DOUBLE QUOTES,  BUT I WANT THAT SERVER WON'T CRASH, AND RESPONSE ME WITH ERROR

I use body-parser package with next code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

I have the next function:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const User = require('../model/User')
const authHelper = require('../helpers/authHelper')
const config = require('../config')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const {
      email,
      password
    } = req.body

    if(!(email || password)) {
      throw new Error('Enter the properties correctly')
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({
      email
    })
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'Email or password is wrong'
    })

    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Email is not found"
    })

    const accessToken = authHelper.generateAccessToken(user._id).token
    const refreshToken = authHelper.generateRefreshToken(user._id).token

    // res.set({
    //   "access-token": accessToken.token,
    //   "refresh-token": refreshToken.token,
    // })

    return res.json({
      "accessToken": accessToken,
      "refreshToken": refreshToken,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    return res.json({
      msg: e.message
    })
  }
}
```

Here is the query

```
{
    email: "test@test.com",
    "password": "test"
}
```

The error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 3
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (R:\Projects\jwt-auth\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at R:\Projects\jwt-auth\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (R:\Projects\jwt-auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (R:\Projects\jwt-auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (R:\Projects\jwt-auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some to edit your post with some details to get a proper answer. Thanks.

Comment: Use a try / catch block ?

Comment: Remember Express is all about having chained handlers, so one that looks for malformed JSON data is something you can add.

Comment: There is no much information on this question to give you a proper answer. Please edit your post to let us known at least how is the function which trows you the error

Comment: I've got an ansewer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819337/catch-express-bodyparser-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819337/catch-express-bodyparser-error/48138247#48138247

Answer (score 0):

Try fix the email key:

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "test"
}
```

JSON object key must be between double cuotes.

Comment: I know, there error - email field must be in double quotes, but I want that server won't crash, and response me with error, I wrote this in a problem

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse(req.body).then(data => console.log("SUCCESS")).catch(err=> console.log("ERR"))

Comment: Just tried it out, nothin happens, but in my server.js file I use body-parser package with next code

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

Comment: Console.log before the `try{}`, right in the first line o the function, then you know if the erro is in the function or in the bodyParse middleware

Answer (score 0):

May the problem is with this struct:

```js
const {
      email,
      password
    } = req.body
```

try:

```js
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Comment: That is default ES6 syntax, but I've tried, server is still crushing